# cssのセレクタで、divタグ内部の文字列が指定した文字列と一致するときだけ指定する方法を知りたい

Tags: javascript, html, css

下記のやりたいことをjavascriptを使わずにcssだけで実現したい場合、
cssのセレクタはどのように指定すればよいのか教えていただきたいです。

### やりたいこと

次のようなdivタグがあったとします。

```
<div class="hoge">りんご</div>
<div class="hoge">ばなな</div>
```

このときに、２個目のdivタグ(=「ばなな」が文字列に入っているdivタグ)のみfontサイズを12pxにしたい

```
.hoge {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

.hogeだけだと両方にきいちゃいますが、文字列の部分一致、完全一致などで二番目のdivタグだけにきかせたいです。

よろしくおねがいします。

Comment: 補足として、2つのdivでclass名は全く同じもので保ちたいです

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cssだけで中身による選択はできないはずです．例えば，以下のような要素に対してマッチすべきかみたいなことを考えると，対応できないというのが何となくわかるのではないでしょうか．

```html
<div class="hoge"><p>ばなな</p><img src="huga.png"/></div>
<div class="hoge"><p>banana</p><img src="ばなな.png"/></div>
```

そのようなセレクタでいうと，属性セレクタ（参考：https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors）が一番近そうな気がします．HTML5では，カスタムデータ属性を自由に付けられるので，冗長ですが`data-content`（名前は適当です）に同じ中身のテキストを与えて，属性セレクタでマッチさせることが可能です．

```html
<div class="hoge" data-content="りんご">りんご</div>
<div class="hoge" data-content="ばなな">ばなな</div>
```

```css
.hoge[data-content="ばなな"] {
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

### 参考

- 本家stack overflowでの同様の質問 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520429/is-there-a-css-selector-for-elements-containing-certain-text

Comment: ありがとうございます。WordPressでの自動生成されるタグについてなのでdata-contentをいじることは難しそうです。javascriptで対応しようかなと思います。